# Toggle buttons - what do you think of using them in SaaS platform if description is still necessary?

Tags: buttons, toggle, view

I'm wondering if using a toggle button to enable different views of the data indicated on the platforms is the right solution, especially if the toggle button needs a description so the user is able to understand it. Does anyone have some opinion regarding it?[image]

Comment: What do you regard the description? 'sort by' ?

Answer (score 2):

#### The core issue is *clarity*, regardless of the control.

We're discussing toggle buttons at the moment, but this is about user understanding. This can apply to any control, which either shifts a view, filters data, or changes a configuration.

**Is switching this toggle a potentially destructive action?**

If this is a UI which is part of a complex configuration, where a choice has some consequences once it's applied, having a visible info tip could tell them what each choice represents.

**Or is this just a view preference?**

If this is the case, just having a hover tip when the cursor appears can be enough to tell them what this choice means.

[image]

Comment: it's just a view preference. The tooltip of course would be applied :)